# Using SQL in MSAccess how can i copy one column into a NEW column in one query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use the following 2 SQL statements to copy the data from one column into a new column in the same table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype

UPDATE table_name 
SET destination_column_name=orig_column_name
WHERE condition_if_necessary
```

Is there a way in which I an achieve the same result using just 1 SQL statement?

Comment: one of the statements is DDL and the other one is DML. So you cannot achieve both of them in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it as a separate `UPDATE`, but this will work for the existing rows only. It will not set the `[destination_column_name]` value when new rows are inserted.